# Cannot Install Labelme in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, anaconda, labelme

I try to install labelme by referring to
https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/tree/main#anaconda

In particular:

[image]

However, when following the procedures, it shows on my Anaconda prompt

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in labelme code and you can report it as an issue. There are characters in README.md in the repo that can't be decoded using your locale (cp950). You can try changing your locale for something that supports UTF-8 (eg: en_us.UTF-8).

Comment: Please don't post images of error message. Always copy/paste the text

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using 'pip install labelme'.
My workaround solution is to install the previous version of labelme.
For example: 'pip install labelme==5.3.0'.